# Problem with people sitting in the train

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I am supposed to solve  the problem:

Ten married couples travel by train in four wagons. How many ways can these 20 people travel if at least one of them has to sit in each wagon, and no married couple wants to travel in the same wagon?

My solution:

$20.18.16.14$  because we take every other person, but that is not correct answer. Or should I use inclusion-exclusion? Can anyone tell me, where is the problem in my solution?

Comment: @Peter Okay so we can say, that it is $10!$ for men and then we want to arrange the women but how? There is just one condition, that married couples cannot sit together

Comment: @Peter Desired result is $61.675.505.664$

Comment: Sorry, now I got the question.

Comment: @Peter Can you please elaborate the answer?

Comment: I got how it is meant, I have no solution yet.

Comment: @Peter Can it be solve in the way that: We have 4 wagons, so $4^{10}$ way of arranging the men and then for each woman, there is three wagons (in the fourth is their husband), so we have $3^{10}$? But the solution does not match

Comment: Use PIE. The condition that "married couple i sits together" is very easy to deal with.

Comment: Lol *no married couple wants to travel in the same wagon* what a wonderful setting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Number of ways to sit 20 married couples in 0 wagons, no married couple in the same wagon, possibly leaving some wagons empty: 0
2. Number of ways to sit 20 married couples in 1 wagons, no married couple in the same wagon, possibly leaving some wagons empty: 0
3. Number of ways to sit 20 married couples in 2 wagons, no married couple in the same wagon, possibly leaving some wagons empty: $2^{10}$
4. Number of ways to sit 20 married couples in 3 wagons, no married couple in the same wagon, possibly leaving some wagons empty: $6^{10}$
5. Number of ways to sit 20 married couples in 4 wagons, no married couple in the same wagon, possibly leaving some wagons empty: $12^{10}$
6. Number of ways to sit 20 married couples in 4 wagons, no married couple in the same wagon, no wagon empty:

$$ 12^{10} - 4 \times 6^{10} - 6 \times 2^{10} + 4 \times 0  - 1 \times 0 = 61675505664.$$

Comment: how exactly you get numbers $ 6^{10}$ and $ 12^{10}$?

Comment: For 3 wagons, each couple has $2 \times {3 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to sit in the 3 wagons. So the total is $6^{10}$. Similarly for 4 wagons, each couples has $2 \times { 4 \choose 2} = 12$ ways to sit.

Comment: Oh, okay thank you so much I wouldn't think of such a solution

Comment: This is standard for such a problem. Just think about how you can force the conditions.